# I try to use polymorphism but my code does not work as i excpected, could anyone help me solve this problem?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, polymorphism, extend

UserManager.java:

```
public class UserManager {
        public void add(User user) {
            System.out.println(user.getUserNumber() + " user added");
        }
}
```

StudentManager.java:

```
public class StudentManager extends UserManager {
    @Override
    public void add(User user) {
        System.out.println(user.getUserNumber() + "  student added");
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student1 = new Student();
        student1.setUserNumber("12345");

        UserManager userManager = new UserManager();       
        userManager.add(student1);

    }
}
```

Expecting Output :12345 student added.

Real output :12345 user added.

Why i get this output ?

Comment: You created a `UserManager` instance, so the `UserManager` method is the one called. That is the expected behaviour. Did you by any chance mean to do `UserManager userManager = new StudentManager();` ?

Comment: Java doesn't magically select your `StudentManager` when you call a `UserManager` with a `Student` object, the `userManager` instance **must be** an instance of `StudentManager`

Comment: Just change `new UserManager()` to `new Studentmanager()`

Comment: If you want magically functionality mention by @Lino you must utilize Vissitor design pattern.

Comment: *"Expecting Output :12345 student added"* - Can you indicate specifically why you expect that output?  It's a fairly standard debugging process to assert "X must be true because Y is true" and then examine your code to see if Y is actually true.  You may find in your case that it isn't.  For example, you may expect that output because you are using a `StudentManager` instance.  But examining your code will find that nowhere are you using a `StudentManager` instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use polyformphism as you expected, you should instantiate the `UserManager` object as `StudentManager`, so the JVM will invoke the overriden `add` method. Here is the right way to do that:

```java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Student student1 = new Student();
       student1.setUserNumber("12345");

       UserManager userManager = new StudentManager();       
       userManager.add(student1);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Lukasz thanks for the editing, I had actually noticed the wrong formatting when I submitted the answer, and I had already edited. Thanks anyway :)